# what happens with items/lists when the creating user is deleted?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have a user `usr1` that i need to remove completely from a site collection.

`usr1` has created several lists and items within these lists.

If i remove the user programmatically:

`ClientContext.Web.SiteUsers.Remove(usr1)`

What happens to the lists and items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing happens with the list or the item, but when a user clicks on the author name (usr1) she won't see the removed users profile page. Unless items have unique permissions only accessible by usr1, you're good to go.